# Use Arrays within the check Box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, checkbox

How can I pass a Array values to check box
I have an Array say loan["1","2","3"] and in my view

```
 <%= check_box_tag "loan[]" ,c.id , true %>
```

For the first time i select the ids and Ill save. But at the second time only selected ids(which i have selected for the first time)  should be displayed and rest should be unchecked.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You must pass two arrays into view - all loans and checked loans.
And in 3rd `check_box_tag` parameter check their interseption, something like this:

```
<% @loans.each do |loan| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "loans[]", loan.id, @checked_loans.any? { |checked_loan| checked_loan.loan_id == loan.id } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have an model Subject, after selecting an id from subject , i have did like this   <% @subjects.each do |c| %> <%= check_box_tag "loan[]" ,c.id,  @subject.loan.any? { |sub| sub.loan_id == loan.id }  %>